# Replace a column value in the spark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

could you please help me to replace column values in dataframes spark:

```
data = [["1", "xxx", "company 0"],
        ["2", "xxx", "company 1"],
        ["3", "company 44", "company 2"],
        ["4", "xxx", "company 1"],
        ["5", "bobby", "company 1"]]


dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to replace "company" with "cmp". "Company" can be met in different columns.

Comment: Can you explain im more detail I didn't get your question?
you would like to change the last column to be cmp.company instead of a company?
I don't even see headers.
Anyway, always assign schema when createDataFrame it will help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the "Company" may appear in any columns, you'd have to loop through each column and apply `regex_replace` onto each of them:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = dataframe.columns

for c in cols:
    dataframe = dataframe.withColumn(c, F.regexp_replace(c, 'company', 'cmp'))

+---+------+-----+
| _1|    _2|   _3|
+---+------+-----+
|  1|   xxx|cmp 0|
|  2|   xxx|cmp 1|
|  3|cmp 44|cmp 2|
|  4|   xxx|cmp 1|
|  5| bobby|cmp 1|
+---+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

functional programming approach

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
cols = dataframe.columns
reduce(lambda dataframe, c: dataframe.withColumn(c, F.regexp_replace(c, 'company', 'cmp')), cols, dataframe).show()
```